# How to pass other variables as args along with std::ostream in a function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, ostream, ansi-c

I was working on a function which looks like so:

```
inline std::ostream& mvUp(int n,std::ostream& ss){
    char u[8];
    sprintf(u,"\033[%dA",n);
    ss<<u;
    return ss;
}
```

and using it like so:

`std::cout<<mvUp(1);`

however it shows error:

```
std::cout<<mvUp(1);
     |          ^_____too few args in function call
     ^_______________no operator "<<" match these operands
```

I also tried: `std::cout<<mvUp(1,std::cout);` but still not working.

```
std::cout<<mvUp(1);
     ^_______________no operator "<<" match these operands
```

now when I try making it template,

```
template <int n>
inline std::ostream& mvUp(std::ostream& ss){
    char u[8];
    sprintf(u,"\033[%dA",n);
    ss<<u;
    return ss;
}
```

and use it: `std::cout<<mvUp<1>`, this works totally fine but the problem with this is that templates take `const` args.

Not able to figure out where am I getting wrong. Also how is it working in templates when I am not passing any args?

Comment: Why are you trying to mix `<<` and functions? Why not just `mvUp(1,std::cout);`?  `std::cout` can accept function pointers which `mvUp<1>` is, so that is the reason why it compiles.

Comment: I want to write a function that outputs something to a ostream that's passed in, and return the stream. I'm not sure if it's that right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern C++ code uses `std::string`, and other classes. This makes implementing this kind of an overload trivial.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

inline std::string mvUp(int n) {
    std::ostringstream o;

    o << "\033[" << n << "A";
    return o.str();
}
```

Then, everything will work automatically:

```
std::cout<<mvUp(1);
```

Your `mvUp` returns `std::string`, and the existing `<<` overload takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that `std::ostream& mvUp(std::ostream& ss);` `std::cout << mvUp<1>` works is *not* a peculiarity of C++ function call syntax.

`std::cout` has its `operator<<` overloaded to accept single-parameter functions like this one, and call them by passing itself as the first argument.

Given `std::ostream& mvUp(int n,std::ostream& ss);`, `std::cout<<mvUp(1)` doesn't work because your function doesn't have one parameter. And `std::cout << mvUp(1,std::cout);` doesn't work because your function returns `std::ostream&`, which can't be printed.

The generic solution is to make a `class` with overloaded `operator<<`. But, as the other answer suggests, here you can just make a function that returns `std::string`, and print its return value.

Comment: Is there any difference or performance issue on using the stream over the function returning string?

Comment: @DarthCucumber If anything, returning a string should be slower. Measure it to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a custom `ostream` manipulator, similar to [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and other manipulators from the `<iomanip>` library.  But what you have written is not the correct way to implement that.  Your manipulator needs to return a type that holds the information you want to manipulate the stream with, and then you need to overload `operator<<` to stream out that type.  That will give you access to the `ostream` which you can then manipulate as needed.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
struct mvUpS
{
    int n;
};

mvUpS mvUp(int n) {
    return mvUpS{n};
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ss, const mvUpS &s) {
    return ss << "\033[" << s.n << "A";
}
```

Now `std::cout << mvUp(1);` will work as expected.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/fGqne0)

Comment: `mvUp` looks a lot like `mvUpS`'ctor, why not put the logic there? `std::cout << mvUpS(1);` will just construct temporaries, no harm in that, right?

Comment: @Quimby `mvUpS(1)` will not work since `mvUpS` does not define a constructor. Add one: `struct mvUpS { int n; myUpS(int n) : n(n) {} };` then it will work. Otherwise use `myUpS{1}` instead. But either way, if at some point in the future, you decide to change the contents of `mvUpS`, you would have to replace `mvUpS(1)`/`mvUpS{1}` accordingly.  With a separate function, you can encapsulate that change better so you don't have to replace `mvUp(1)` each time. This is how the standard parameterized manipulators are implemented.